# Cannot find name require Angular2

Tags: json, angular, typescript

am trying to learn angular doing a schedulerApp.
here is my code :

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {ExperimentsComponent} from './experiments/experiments.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {calendrierComponent} from './calendrier/calendrier.component';
import {StateService} from './common/state.service';
import {ExperimentsService} from './common/experiments.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.html'),
  styles: [ require('./app.component.css')],
  directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES ],
  providers: [StateService, ExperimentsService],
})
@Routes([
  {path: '/',            component: HomeComponent },
  {path: '/home',        component: HomeComponent },
  {path: '/about',       component: AboutComponent },
  {path: '/experiments', component: ExperimentsComponent },
  {path: '/calendrier',  component: calendrierComponent },
  {path: '/*',           component: HomeComponent }
])
export class AppComponent {}
```

when i add these lines :

```
import {calendrierComponent} from './calendrier/calendrier.component';

@Routes([
  {path: '/calendrier',  component: calendrierComponent },
])
```

i have these errors :

```
Error   Typescript  Cannot find name 'require'. 12:13
Error   Typescript  Cannot find name 'require'. 13:13
```

i tried to add "   "types": [ "node" ] " on my ts.config.json but it didn't do anything... Did you have some idea to unstuck me ? thanks you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your component should be like that. you can not use `require` in angular 4. also `directives` depreciate in [angular 2 & 4](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#summary). see (app.module.ts) so you need to pass it in providers in component or declarations in module

```
 import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router';
    import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
    import {ExperimentsComponent} from './experiments/experiments.component';
    import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
    import {calendrierComponent} from './calendrier/calendrier.component';
    import {StateService} from './common/state.service';
    import {ExperimentsService} from './common/experiments.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers: [StateService, ExperimentsService, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    })
    @Routes([
      {path: '/',            component: HomeComponent },
      {path: '/home',        component: HomeComponent },
      {path: '/about',       component: AboutComponent },
      {path: '/experiments', component: ExperimentsComponent },
      {path: '/calendrier',  component: calendrierComponent },
      {path: '/*',           component: HomeComponent }
    ])
    export class AppComponent {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use `require`. You can pass the file paths directly using the `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` options. Angular will automatically resolve the styles and templates based on the paths:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [StateService, ExperimentsService],
})
```